# android studio clear .gradle on C:\Users\Administrator,can't find one of the classpath

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

The ERROR:
   [image: error]

my app gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.tencent.mm:AndResGuard-gradle-plugin:1.1.8'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

i am sry for that the code can't post,so what i said this sentence is nonsense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you open the url mentioned you will find that this version `1.1.8` does not exist in `jcenter` repository. The available versions there are:

https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/tencent/mm/AndResGuard-gradle-plugin/

```
1.2.3/
1.2.4/    
1.2.5-RC1/    
1.2.5/   
1.2.6/   
1.2.7/
```

So either upgrade your `AndResGuard-gradle-plugin` to a `1.2.x` version or change the `jcenter` repository in by adding `maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/simsun/maven' }`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/simsun/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.tencent.mm:AndResGuard-gradle-plugin:1.1.8'
        classpath 'org.greenrobot:greendao-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```